# Wordpress backend textarea adding and saving

Tags: php

I'm trying to move from simple text input to textarea, but really don't know how to put value afterward into it. I dont code, but i tried really hard for few hours to edit this code

following this man: https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-add-a-custom-user-field-in-wordpress/ but really messed it up. My goal is to have a textarea with multiple lines saved as WordPress user meta and also displayed in backend. This user meta to the database now doesn't work and is not displaying in backend.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $added_books = get_the_author_meta( 'added_books', $user->ID );
    ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="added_books"><?php esc_html_e( 'Added books: ', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
            <textarea id="added_books" name="added_books" ><?php echo ( $added_books ); ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );

function crf_update_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['added_books'] ) && sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['added_books'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'added_books', sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['added_books'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details as to the problem? a description of what you expect to happen vs what's actually happening would go a long way here :)

Comment: `textarea with multiple lines` - Line returns are not displayed on HTML pages, so you'll want to add CSS to show them `white-space:pre` at some point.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space  I would avoid converting Line endings to `<br>` as that is just a mess.

Comment: This is wrong too `<input ...></input>` input is a self closing tag (you may get 2 inputs here).  `<input ... />` but for a textarea `<textarea id="added_books" name="added_books" ><?php echo ( $added_books ); ?></textarea>"`  Do not put any space between the open and close `textarea` tags.  If you do then `white-space:pre` (as I suggested above) will include those as well.  One problem with a textarea is it's just a block of text, you cant easily force an end user to put in 3 and only 3 lines, or put them in a specific order.  Something to keep in mind.

Comment: `<?php echo ( $added_books ); ?>` XSS attack incoming... see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I just added your suggestions, plus when updating data, i added sanitize_textarea_field, but now it dont even save itself to a database and is not displaying at backend. And just a note, end user wont have a option to enter in this field. Thanks so much for help!

Comment: @schu34 Hi! I just added a few comments and edited the code a bit. I want to have an textarea field in single user backend of wordpress and with normal text this code was working fine - saving itself to database and displaying on backend, but now with textarea, i dont know why it isnt working similarly

Comment: @Geoffrey sorry, I'm not a programmer - can you make an sugeestion what to change so that XSS attack cant happen?